# AutoFac and resolving objects down the chain

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

Using WebAPI, and interfaces for my Repos, AutoFac appears to be trying to instantiate my `UserRepoitory`, but when it tries to creates the instances, it gets stuck at *their* constructors.

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on 
type 'Db.UserRepository' can be invoked with the available services 
and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Db.DbContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Db.DbContext)'.
```

---

```
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        DbContext db = null;

        public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        } 
    }

    public class FindABriefContext : DbContext
    {
        public FindABriefContext() : base("FindABriefContext")
        {}
    }
```

---

Nothing special in my DI code..

```
public static void RegisterContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UserController).Assembly);

            //var asm = typeof(IUserRepository).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserRepository).Assembly)
                .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            var container = builder.Build();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver= new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for container to instantiate Repository it needs to satisfy its dependency on DBContext. That is why you need to tell Autofac how to resolve DbContext.

Simply add the following line

```
builder.RegisterType<FindABriefContext>().As<DbContext>();
```

before

```
var container = builder.Builder();
```

Comment: Thanks for that - It just didn't work for me - went down the ` builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());` route instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, then you must have another unregistered dependencies that you did not mention here. It looks like you tried to make Autofac behave like Unity by using AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource, which registers ALL concrete types it can find. It depends on your application, its lifetime etc, but registering all types is certainly not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the context in as a parameter in your repository.

From autofac documentation:

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigReader>()
       .As<IConfigReader>()
       .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "sectionName"));
```

Or I would use a factory and just inject the factory instead of injecting all of your repositories.

```
public class RepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
        public IRepository<T> CreateRepository<T>() where T : class
        {
            var yourContext = new SomeContext(); //can also be injected
            return new Repository<T>(yourContext);
        }
}
```

Then you would just inject the single factory.

```
builder.RegisterType<RepositoryFactory>().As<IRepositoryFactory>();
```

Comment: Factory Pattern works for me - i'll give that a shot..., and report back.

Comment: Infact - thinking about it, it does't work for me, I don't use generic repos - I'll move back to Unity.

Comment: There is still the option of using the first part of the answer ".WithParameter" and pass your context into the repos. Just as you have it now add it to the end: .AsImplementedInterfaces().WithParameter(...